# MGtwitter Login Error

Tags: iphone, mgtwitterengine

Hi I am using MGtwitter with Oauth . First time it shows login popup. But when I am trying to login it is giving following exception

> -[OAToken setPin:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x685a580
>   2011-05-13 11:17:03.177 Twit[3491:207]
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[OAToken setPin:]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0x685a580'

It is working fine earlier .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't implemented the method `setPin` or have released the controller.

Comment: I noticed that In Void setPin method  _accessToken.pin = pin is giving this exception.I comment it and now it is working..what is this

Comment: I think pin is not required fot client type app

Comment: You may want to post some code in your question so that the exact cause can be known. Looks like its related to the property of the variables.